# Move containing values only up and down with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div

```
  <div>
  <div id='mydiv1'><textarea id='mytask1'>hai</textarea></div>
 <div id='mydiv2'><textarea id='mytask2'>hello</textarea></div>
  </div>
```

I have to change this div to when I click move up button in second textarea

```
 <div>
 <div id='mydiv1'><textarea id='mytask1'>hello</textarea></div>
 <div id='mydiv2'><textarea id='mytask2'>hai</textarea></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnyzrcp/)

### Updated assuming ids aren't known [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnyzrcp/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id='mydiv1'><textarea id='mytask1'>hai</textarea></div>
  <div id='mydiv2'><textarea id='mytask2'>hello</textarea></div>
  <button>Swap</button>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var div1 = $('#mytask1').val();
    var div2 = $('#mytask2').val();
    $('#mytask1').val(div2);
    $('#mytask2').val(div1);
});
```

Comment: No, that's just a placeholder as the OP didn't give a id or description of the button.

Comment: there is also a up button.when i click the upbutton change interchange the values only

Comment: Show out `upButton` with the selector for your button, `$('#upButton')` for example.

Comment: but id of div are always change

Comment: we don't know what is exact id.it's automatically generated.i want to only interchange the values to above div

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand , you want to move the container instead of only text.
Try the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3fwheudf/)

**code**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
          $('#mydiv2').after($('#mydiv1'));  
    });
});
```

**Edit** 
In case you want to swap the containers on Each Click change the code as

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var first = $('#mydiv1').parent().find("div:first");
          first.next().after(first);  
    });
});
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fwheudf/1/)**

Hope it helps;